# Deduplication in build.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

There are conflicting jline jar files in the includes path that need to be deduplicated.  I have attempted to do so as follows:

I am building a combined spark and kafka fat jar and the jline jar file is duplicated.

Here is the build.sbt file

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._
import java.io.File
import AssemblyKeys._

name := "kafkascala"

version      := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "0.9.1",
 "org.apache.spark" % "spark-examples_2.10" % "0.9.1",
 "org.apache.spark" % "spark-tools_2.10" % "0.9.1",
 "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka_2.10" % "0.8.1.1"   intransitive()
withSources
)

resolvers += "Apache repo" at "https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases"

assemblySettings

mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) => {
    case PathList("maven","jline","jline","pom.properties") => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x => old(x)
  }
}
```

Here is the error output from running  **sbt assembly**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
C:\Users\S80035683\.ivy2\cache\jline\jline\jars\jline-0.9.94.jar:META-INF/maven/jline/jline/pom.properties
C:\Users\S80035683\.ivy2\cache\org.jruby\jruby-complete\jars\jruby-complete-1.6.5.jar:META-INF/maven/jline/jline/pom.properties
        at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$.sbtassembly$Plugin$Assembly$$applyStrategy$1(Plugin.scala:253)
        at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$$anonfun$15.apply(Plugin.scala:270)
        at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$$anonfun$15.apply(Plugin.scala:267)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
        at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$.applyStrategies(Plugin.scala:272)
        at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$.x$4$lzycompute$1(Plugin.scala:172)
        at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$.x$4$1(Plugin.scala:170)
        at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$.stratMapping$lzycompute$1(Plugin.scala:170)
        at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$.stratMapping$1(Plugin.scala:170)
        at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$.inputs$lzycompute$1(Plugin.scala:214)
        at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$.inputs$1(Plugin.scala:204)
        at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$.apply(Plugin.scala:230)
        at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$$anonfun$assemblyTask$1.apply(Plugin.scala:373)
        at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$$anonfun$assemblyTask$1.apply(Plugin.scala:370)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[error] (*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] C:\Users\S80035683\.ivy2\cache\jline\jline\jars\jline-0.9.94.jar:META-INF/maven/jline/jline/pom.properties
[error] C:\Users\S80035683\.ivy2\cache\org.jruby\jruby-complete\jars\jruby-complete-1.6.5.jar:META-INF/maven/jline/jline/pom.properties
```

Here is the section of build.sbt that was attempting to address the issue:

```
assemblySettings

mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) => {
    case PathList("maven","jline","jline","pom.properties") => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x => old(x)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `PathList` is wrong. You're missing `"META-INF"` in front of the `"maven"`. Something like this should work:

```
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) => {
    case PathList("META-INF", "maven","jline","jline", "pom.properties" ) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("META-INF", "maven","jline","jline", "pom.xml" ) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x => old(x)
  } 
}
```

or a bit more concise (exclude both pom.properties and pom.xml in one line):

```
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) => {
    case PathList("META-INF", "maven","jline","jline", ps) if ps.startsWith("pom") => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x => old(x)
  } 
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  You are correct.  And you now (after having accepted and upvoted your answer) have almost identical reputation as myself.

Comment: I am running into a long series of deduplications. Is there any way to see them all at one shot - instead of running sbt assembly many times?

Comment: Maybe it will be better if you just exclude duplicated dependencies as specified here https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#exclude-specific-transitive-deps, but a hacky way I think would be to just have one case like this `case x => 
        val oldStrategy = old(x)
        if (oldStrategy == MergeStrategy.deduplicate)  MergeStrategy.discard else oldStrategy`

Answer (score 2):

I have reached the conclusion that the `defaultMergeStrategy` in sbt is unnecessarily causing deduplicate errors. According to the sbt assembly author the decision to fail rather than select first is because they believe the user should have to explicitly decide, but most users don't even know what the error means and takes them ages to figure out that changing `deduplicate` to `first` just makes stuff work.  I think making the build fail was a mistake, the following is how the `defaultMergeStrategy` should look:

```
// Strat copied from defaultMergeStrategy with the 
// "fail and confuse the hell out the user" lines changed to
// "just bloody work and stop pissing everyone off"
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) ((old) => {
  case x if Assembly.isConfigFile(x) =>
    MergeStrategy.concat
  case PathList(ps @ _*) if Assembly.isReadme(ps.last) || Assembly.isLicenseFile(ps.last) =>
    MergeStrategy.rename
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) =>
    (xs map {_.toLowerCase}) match {
      case ("manifest.mf" :: Nil) | ("index.list" :: Nil) | ("dependencies" :: Nil) =>
        MergeStrategy.discard
      case ps @ (x :: xs) if ps.last.endsWith(".sf") || ps.last.endsWith(".dsa") =>
        MergeStrategy.discard
      case "plexus" :: xs =>
        MergeStrategy.discard
      case "services" :: xs =>
        MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
      case ("spring.schemas" :: Nil) | ("spring.handlers" :: Nil) =>
        MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
      case _ => MergeStrategy.first // Changed deduplicate to first
    }
  case PathList(_*) => MergeStrategy.first // added this line
})
```